# RandomMove Method Tic Tac Toe Not Functional

Tags: java, random, recursion, stack-overflow

I am working on creating a tic tac toe game that allows the user to play against a computer. When the user selects a button on the board, the AI will detect if there is a possible three combo. If there is no threat detected, than the computer will pick a spot randomly on the board to move.

However, my problem is when I make a certain move, the computer sometimes places a move and sometimes get skipped. I was wondering how to fix this, my `randomMove()` method is displayed below.

Would this situation call for a recursive method (my teacher briefly told me this might be necessary) or otherwise? If it is recursive, can you explain it? Thanks for any help!

```
public void RandomMove()
{
    Random x = new Random();
    int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
    if (buttons[y].getText().equals("O") || buttons[y].getText().equals("X")) {
        RandomMove();
    }
    else {
        buttons[y].setText("O");
        buttons[y].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

More specifically I get this error sometimes:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Are you hanaa's friend?  Both the [code and problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8936335/418556) seem *very* familiar.

Comment: If one of the solutions worked, please mark it as correct.

Comment: yeah i am. but i figured out the problem, and could not reach him to tell him to change the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random x = new Random();
```

By creating a new [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) every time the method is called (in a potentially recursive method), the code will 'choke'.  The reason is that the `Random` instance is seeded with the current time in milliseconds, thereafter the **sequence** of numbers it will produce is 'set in stone'.  The method will complete many times within a single millisecond, creating many `Random` objects.

Instead, the (poorly named) `x` should be declared as a class attribute and created once only.

Answer (score 2):

Working off of Andrew Thompson's answer, try replacing

```
Random x = new Random();
int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
```

with this

```
int y = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
```

Comment: Good call on `Math.random()`.  I was considering mentioning it.